# How use ajax post when datepicker change date?

Tags: ajax, jquery, datepicker

Good afternoon

Value in input change with datepicker ui.

I want use ajax post when value in input will be change.

For this i use script:

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker" id="datepicker">

$(".datepicker").datepicker({changeYear: true});

$(".datepicker").on("change",function(){
var date=$(this).val();
$.post("test.php", {
date:date
},
function(data){$('#testdiv').html('');$('#testdiv').html(data);
});
});
```

But ajax post query is executed with the old date.

Datepicker does not have time change value in input.

Tell me how to do query after datepicker change the date in the field?

Me need:

1) datepicker change the date;

2) query should be send with new date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can trigger ajax post on datepicker events:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({

    onSelect: function(date, instance) {

        $.ajax
        ({
              type: "Post",
              url: "www.example.com",
              data: "date="+date,
              success: function(result)
              {
                  //do something
              }
         });  
     }
});
```

Hope this helps- @Codebrain

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should consider using `onSelect` event of the datepicker (see [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)).

Using that event, the newly selected date (as string) is passed as the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `changeDate`

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
 .on('changeDate', function(e) {
    // `e` here contains the extra attributes
});
```

you can check here : http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `on(change` you have `onSelect` for datepicker, which will fire when the date is changed.

```
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect:function(dateText,instance){
            alert(dateText); //Latest selected date will give the alert.
            $.post("test.php", {
            date:dateText // now you will get the selected date to `date` in your post
            },
            function(data){$('#testdiv').html('');$('#testdiv').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.